# Focused input changes background of separate div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project, and I am a bit stumped here, and maybe someone has a idea on what can be done. I am working on a system where I will be having 6 input sections for color options for a system I am working on, and what I am looking at doing is pending on which input they are currently focused on, it would show a specific background image in a div off to the right of the system which would basically be a diagram showing what that specific input affects.

Here is an example image:
[image]

I been thinking if its possible using CSS only like using :focus, but what I have found out there on it just didn't help. I am sure I could do it with jQuery, but, I know next to nothing in jQuery. The form, I can easily make but, having it change the background image of the specific div is where I am stuck at.

Any thoughts/help is appreciated.

EDIT:
example how I first approached this with CSS was like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#test:focus + #test3{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#test2:focus + #test3{
    background-color: red;
}
#test3{
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<form>
Input #1: <input id="test" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Input #2: <input id="test2" type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<br>
<div id="test3">&nbsp;</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you're asking is too broad and unclear. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: I have removed the PHP tag since the question has nothing to do with PHP. You can almost do this with CSS alone on a browser that supports :focus-within, so I am going to answer what you implied: How do I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Please include some code. Your HTML for a start then perhaps show us what you have tried with `:focus`. Best option of all is to provide a [MCVE] . A top tip here would to be to use CSS spriting for the background image, that way images don't need to be downloaded on demand on item focus.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, I don't think it was too broad of a question since JasonB pretty much answered what I was looking for. I was unsure of how i was going to go about it with or without using jQuery.

Comment: @JasonB thanks for removing the tag, Also thanks for the jQuery, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The reason it could be considered too broad is that you have not given us much context to work with. By  giving us your basic HTML structure and existing CSS you narrow the scope of the question and give us  more context to work with. We don't have to "make up" as much. Also by providing more context it often provides a clearer picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jon P Well, at the time, I didn't have any current markup because I wasn't sure on how I was going to go about it. I did update my first question with an example of pretty much what I have tried. The form is easy enough to do and the styling of where the inputs and the div for the image is also easy enough to do, it was just the matter of having the background image of the div change pending on what input they were in. As for your previous post, using a sprite is exactly what I was going to do, but as not being a pertiante part of the question that I was asking, I didn't mention it.

Comment: Ah, the missing piece of the puzzle. Looking at your code, I can see the problem with what you tried. By having `#test3` out of the `form` it is not a sibling of the `input` elements as they do not share the same parent element. I'll update my CSS only answer below to include the form tags for reference.

Comment: [Your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52048644/1) contained no code which made it unclear. As for the too broad; that could have been applicable with no code. In the future, please include code so we can leave out the guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable with CSS.

Keep the display area a sibling of the inputs and absolutely position the display area.

You can then use the [general sibling sector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` in conjunction with `:focus` to achieve what you want. In your code you are using `+`, which is the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```css
.input-column {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.input-column input {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.input-column label {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  clear: left;
}

.display-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.bill:focus~.display-area {
  background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200');
}

.billGrey:focus~.display-area {
  background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200');
}

.nick:focus~.display-area {
  background-image: url('https://www.placecage.com/200/200');
}

.nickGrey:focus~.display-area {
  background-image: url('https://www.placecage.com/g/200/200');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-column">
    <!-- <form> could also go here -->

    <label for="bill">Bill</label> <input id="bill" class="bill">
    <label for="billGrey">Grey Bill</label><input id="billGrey" class="billGrey">
    <label for="nickGrey">Grey Nick</label><input id="nickGrey" class="nickGrey">
    <label for="nick">Nick</label><input id="nick" class="nick">

    <div class="display-area">
    </div>
    <!-- </form> alternate postion -->
  </div>
</form>
```

This can be improved by using [CSS sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) to eliminate the delay in loading subsequent images

Comment: Is there a way to use this when the input type is color? I noticed when I tried, it became unfocused until after selecting the color.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the color selector itself now has focus, not the field. Only one element at a time can have focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some jQuery code to accomplish what you want to do. 
You can replace the `data-color` attribute with a `data-url` attribute and use that to set the background. There is not a lot of code here, just `$( element).on( 'focus', function() {...}` which is a commonly used jQuery event handling structure.

If you don't want to reset the background when you leave the input you can skip the event handler tied to the blur event.

```js
const displayArea = $( '.display-area' );

$( 'input' ).on( 'focus', function() {
  const color = $( this ).data( 'color' );
  displayArea.css( 'background', color );
});

$( 'input' ).on( 'blur', function() {
  displayArea.css( 'background', '' );
});
```

```css
.form-row {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

.input-column {
margin: -5px;
}

.input-column input {
display: block;
margin: 5px;
}

.display-area {
margin-left: 10px;
background: red;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="input-column">
    <input data-color="green">
    <input data-color="blue">
    <input data-color="yellow">
    <input data-color="orange">
  </div>
  <div class="display-area">
  </div>
```